# Embedded jpg from remote raw file, only?

Tags: http, image-processing, metadata, file-handling

Lets say I have a RAW-image on a remote server, like this www.mydomain.com/DSC0001.ARW, and I would like to **only** extract the "small" preview image (jpg) from that raw file, without having to download the whole raw-file, is that possible somehow?

Comment: Sorry - been offline for a couple of days. Will give your updated version a try asap, and get back, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Again**

Ok, it appears that the server on which you have the raw files is not actually yours, so you cannot extract the preview image on the server as I suggested... however, you can download just a part of the 25MB image and then extract locally. So, here I download just the first 1MB from a file on a server I don't own onto my local machine and then extract the preview locally:

```
curl -r 0-1000000 http://www.rawsamples.ch/raws/sony/RAW_SONY_ILCA-77M2.ARW > partial.arw
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  976k  100  976k    0     0   984k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  983k

exiftool -b -PreviewImage -W! preview.jpg partial.arw
```

You may need to experiment with how much of the file you need to download, depending on the camera and its settings etc.

**Updated Answer**

Actually, it is easier to use **exiftool** to extract the preview on the server as (being just a Perl script) it is miles simpler to install than **ImageMagick**.

Here is how to extract the Preview from a Sony ARW file at the command line:

```
exiftool -b -PreviewImage -W! preview.jpg sample.arw
```

That will extract the Preview from `sample.arw` into a file called `preview.jpg`.

So, you would put a PHP script on your server (naming  it `preview.php`) that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -f
<?php
$image=$_GET['image'];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
exec("exiftool -b -PreviewImage -W! preview.jpg $image");
readfile("preview.jpg");
?>
```

and it will extract the Preview from the parameter named `image` and send it back to you as a JPEG.

Depending on your server setup and file naming, the invocation will be something like:

```
http://yourserver/preview.php?image=sample.arw
```

Note that you will need to do a little more work if the server is multi-user because as it is I have fixed the name of the preview file as `preview.jpg` which means two simultaneous users could potentially clash.

**Original Answer**

That's quite easy if you can run **ImageMagick** on your server, you could run a little PHP script that takes the image name as a parameter, extracts the thumbnail and sends you a JPEG.

I presume you mean a Sony Alpha raw image.

Comment: Yes, that part I know.

Comment: However, that still means I need to request/download the whole raw file from the remote server before I can extract that jpeg. I am trying to find a way where you only need to request/download a specific part from the file in order to make this thumbnail preview fast..

Comment: No, the JPEG is extracted on the server using **ImageMagick** as I said and just the thumbnail is sent to the client. If you provide a raw Sony image, I will try and demonstrate.

Comment: Please have another look, I have added a load more detail and code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, and that is totally working. However, that does not take away the request issue so to speak, since I still need to request that complete file in order to extract the jpeg. Im looking for a way where I dont need to download the whole file, like 25 mb, in order to extract the jpeg file.. Im looking for a way that you ask for a specific RAW file, and it will only download the necessary part of that file in order to serve the preview jpeg. Do you see what I mean? Or am I missing out on something?

Comment: The code shown does exactly what you ask. You send a request to the server (around 100 bytes long), it reads the ARW file (around 20MB) and exteacts the JPEG into a file on the server (around 1MB), and sends it to your browser. The ARW file does not *"cross the wire"*.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but still, that requires the server to download that file, BEFORE it can extract the preview file... so Im looking for a way where you dont need to download the 20mb, just the necessary parts of that 20 mb file in order to extract only the part I need. You see what I mean?

Comment: You said the file is already on your server in your very first sentence.... *"Let's say we have a raw file on a remote server..."*

Comment: Where did I say on _my_ server? :) It looks like I said remote server in that sentence, which is not my own computer, it is something I have access to located somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer to match your situation - please have another look.

Answer (score 1):

Let me preface this with: I am no image processing expert.

## Answer to your question

You can show images resized, but this will still download the entire file. To my mind, that means the best approach would be to save a pre-processed thumbnail of that image alongside the raw image. If you use some naming convention like `DSC0001.ARW.thumbnail.png`, they should be easy to find.

## Possible alternative solution on the AWS stack

Probably only a realistic solution if you are willing to get involved with some code and AWS. If you use AWS S3 for storing your images, you could fire an event off to AWS Lambda to run a script which processes your raw file into the thumbnail and save that to S3 for you; whenever you upload a new raw file.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean... I've been into those thoughts too, around the fire off event style, when uploading something new... But, would be great if there is a way to just read the necessary part of the file in order to get the preview jpg from the raw-file. But it guess that might be hard, then....

Comment: @nickelman the problem is that in order to read only parts from the server (which you can do via the range request header property) is that it would produce significant overhead for each request/response, and there would be a lot making it slow and not save much on traffic. I believe ARW is basically a TIFF but in any case, you need to be able to parse and handle the format manually with all its caveats. I agree with AkkarinZA that the best solution is to produce a thumb on the server (or client) and serve that.